# Updating objects with SOAP API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, dml-operations

I've set up a chat for my Salesforce Org and I want to change the chat capacity through code. From the Salesforce documentation (see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_presenceuserconfig.htm)) it is possible to update the PresenceUserConfig. I want to update the capacity and have tried doing so with regular Apex code updating the object. This leads to DML operation errors on the object.

It seems that I only can update the objects with the SOAP API. Can anyone confirm if this is the correct way to do it? I want to update the object through Apex code so I can keep my code dynamic. I've looked into doing so with WSDL files. But I only get errors when importing it to Apex classes. If someone could guide me in the correct direction as I've been hitting the wall with this issue for over 3 days now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with either the SOAP or REST API. Here's an example I built in Workbench:

[image: PresenceUserConfig in workbench]

You don't need a WSDL, just make the appropriate JSON and make the call.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/52.0/sobjects/PresenceUserConfig');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setBody(
    JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
            'Capacity' => 20,
            'DeveloperName' => 'Fox',
            'MasterLabel' => 'Fox',
            'OptionsIsAutoAcceptEnabled' => true,
            'OptionsIsDeclineEnabled' => false,
            'OptionsIsDeclineReasonEnabled' => false,
            'OptionsIsDisconnectSoundEnabled' => true,
            'OptionsIsRequestSoundEnabled' => true
        }
    )
);
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

You will need to make additional modifications to the above code, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When you set an endpoint, you specify '/services/data/52.0/sobjects/PresenceUserConfig'. How did you acquire this url? I have to make that specific to my code.

Comment: @Nonya Start with the [REST API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/). The first part, `/services/data/` is the root for all API requests, `52.0` is the API version to use, and the remaining parts describe the specific action you wish to perform with the API.

Comment: @sfdxfox I see. So in theory the endpoint you specified in that sample code should work? I've tried using it and modifying it but I get errors:
|System.HttpResponse[Status=Unsupported Media Type, StatusCode=415].

Comment: @Nonya I think I forgot `req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')`.

Comment: would this line replace the previous `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());`? If so another error presents itself, 401 error. This indicates lack of privileges, which probably occurs from removing userinfo? When checking the url endpoint, I get an xml file with this format:
`<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>`
Could this be the reason for the error?

Comment: @Nonya Lightning doesn't include API access, so you may need something [like this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/289665/2984).